# Are there any non cosmetic rewards for completing requests in New Pokémon Snap?

Tags: new-pokemon-snap

I've completed a few random requests, but they've only given me useless stickers and titles.

Is there a point to completing them other than for those things?  For instance, do they give you research level points, or unlock new abilities/levels, or count towards your photodex score, or *anything* gameplay related?

Comment: Think those requests are also good pointers to star ratings you may not have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the requests are meant to be hints for poses or pokemon that are hard to find, rather than being bonus tasks.

I've now done most of them, and there don't seem to be any non-cosmetic rewards other than finding a new pose/pokemon I didn't already have.